# IE9 rendering different markup (HTML) from other browsers - This is not a CSS issue

Tags: php, magento, internet-explorer-9, html-lists

Edit - After some troubleshooting it seem that this problem was related to a plugin I had installed. Disabling plugin fixed the issue.

I have a strange issue with IE9 where it is rendering incorrect markup of an < ol > element. It is placing some of its contained < li > elements on a different part of the DOM tree, so that

```
<div id="Containter">
  <div id="left">
   <ol>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item2</li>
     <li>item3</li>
     <li>item4</li>
   </ol>
  </div><!-- end left -->
 </div><!-- end container -->
```

becomes

```
<div id="Containter">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <div id="left">
   <ol>
     <li>item3</li>
     <li>item4</li>
   </ol>
  </div><!-- end left -->
 </div><!-- end container -->
```

How is this possible!?

The markup is generated by some quite convoluted Javacript PHP on the Magento side so this confuses the issue somewhat. It may be related to these issues, [Is there a way to work around this issue with ordered lists and update panels in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430530/is-there-a-way-to-work-around-this-issue-with-ordered-lists-and-update-panels-in) or this issue [Dynamic HTML rendering issue in IE9 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346385/dynamic-html-rendering-issue-in-ie9-only) although I don't understand how.

This does not explain what is going on however. Switching the browser to IE7 Mode corrects the markup, so forcing this may be a workaround.

Still, I would like to understand what on earth is going on here, and if there is another way to fix it. Screenshots attached.[image]

Any insight gratefully received.

.

Comment: This is most probably an issue relating to invalid html. Run your source html through a validator such as http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: Can you confirm the doctype ? And can we have some real html (not just pseudo code) ?

Comment: Quoting "container" would be a good start, make sure the document is fully valid...

Comment: Have you run the (full) html through the w3c validator?

Comment: @dystroy XHTML 1.0 Strict is the doc type. I didn't post the html because the source views are both (depending which browser) around 900 lines long. I felt it was more a general question about the way pages where rendered. Please see my later comment

Comment: @Ash thanks for your suggestion. My problem is, this relates to the HTML rendered by basket. Linking to this with WC3 validator only checks the 'you have an empty basket' page and not the dynamic content. :(

Comment: @happilyUnStuck The problem is that you probably have a bug in your html and we can't fix it without the code. You should try to reduce your html to the minimal code having the problem. Then it will probably be evident, or else you'll be able to show it.

Comment: Update, I think  it may relate to the version of Prototype used by Magento and it's pre quirks mode IE9 conditionals. http://magebase.com/magento-articles/ie9-issues-with-magento-fix-workaround/comment-page-1/#comment-1046

Comment: @dystroy I 'know' there is a bug in my html. That's the problem ;) my question relates to which one of umpteen  phtml, js and php files which have been parsed by the browser, might be causing IE9 to produce said bug. I switched back to the default theme, which didn't help. I turned off plugins related to the checkout, which does help. Thanks for the prompting, I might finally have some code to post afterall

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you write invalid markup, for example, an `a` tag within another `a` tag, or something like that, IE will either duplicate some tags or alter the HTML.

You should go through and make sure you aren't writing anything silly in there, its probably your problem.

Comment: Is your experience of this related to Javascript in anyway? I understand that not closing tags or block elements inside inline one,s can cause layout issues, and I'm not saying I'm above making errors of this type. However, to completely transplant an element to a totally separate branch of the DOM? This seems far fetched maybe?

Comment: it shouldn't be related to javascript

Comment: the only way it could be related to the javascript is if the javascript itself wrote that HTML

Comment: I don't think the Javascript was responsible for writing that particular section of the page, however disabling a plugin relating to that area of the site fixed the problem. Is it possible that some error in this code caused the browser to parse the page in an unusual order perhaps? It remains a mystery to me

Comment: I don't believe so, please check your html very carefully

Answer (score 0):

Remember to troubleshoot properly. First I disabled my theme. No dice. Then I systematically disabled plugins relation to this section of my theme until the problem went away.

Re-enabled custom theme. Site now renders correctly.

Moral of the story. Don't get precious about your problems, your initial hunch may not be the correct path to happiness.